# How to correctly set up Amazon Route 53, CloudFront with custom origin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I am currently using **Amazon Route 53** for my DNS setup and a custom origin (web server outside of Amazon). I'd like to add **CloudFront** to the mix but I'm not too sure how to set it up?

I've seen Amazon's guide on setting up S3 with Route 53 and CloudFront, but I can't seem to locate any information on doing all this with a custom origin.

Should I be setting it up to work as follows?

1. CloudFront pulls the data from the naked domain's IP address
2. The 'www' is just an alias of the CloudFront distribution

I originally planned to host my content on S3 but decided against it because I'd like more control over the hosting (for example, having the ability to use an .htaccess file and ban hacker IPs, etc).

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK so this is how I managed to solve it in the end:

**Origin Server:**

- In cPanel (on my origin server) I created a sub-domain called `origin.domain.com`
- `origin.domain.com` shares the same document root as `domain.com`
- My .htaccess file redirects `domain.com` to `www.domain.com`:

**Amazon CloudFront:**

- The "Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs)" is set to `www.domain.com`
- The origin is set to `origin.domain.com`

**Amazon Route 53**

- The A record for `domain.com` is set to my origin server's IP address
- The A record for `www.domain.com` is set to an alias for the CloudFront distribution
- `origin.domain.com` is a CNAME for `domain.com`

Thanks to Matt Houser and Bruce P for their help, by the way. :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your have your origin at `origin.domain.com`, create your CloudFront distribution, using http://origin.domain.com as the origin.

Create your `www.domain.com` DNS entry in Route 53, making it an "Alias" for the CloudFront distribution.

One possible alternative to .htaccess is to use WAF on your CloudFront distribution. This way, you can permit/deny based on IP address.

Comment: Would that still work if my web server's .htaccess redirects the naked domain to the 'www' version?

Comment: No.  That would result in a redirect loop.  Client tries to fetch `www.domain.com` -> CloudFront fetches from `origin.domain.com` -> origin says "location is `www.domain.com`, causing CloudFront to try to fetch from `www.domain.com`, and so on.  Update your .htaccess to allow both www.domain.com and origin.domain.com and you should be all set.

Comment: I would suggest the following: have your origin server listen to only `origin.domain.com` without any redirects. `www.domain.com` is handled by CloudFront only and forwards to `origin.domain.com`. `domain.com` can redirect to `www.domain.com` by way of an S3 bucket with redirect rules setup.

Comment: Direct `domain.com` to `www.domain.com` using an S3 bucket with redirect website rules. This will handle your redirect requirement without needing .htaccess.