# Connecting AWS Lightsail, Route 53, and Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, amazon-lightsail

I have recently created a cloudfront distribution (using the LightSail admin area) for a Lightsail instance running Plesk on Ubuntu. I have created custom domains and validated them and they are "Valid, in use".

My domain is hosted through Route 53. When I delete the static IP address value of the apex domain record by changing the "Value/Route traffic to" an "Alias to CloudFront distribution" and then paste the distribution address, (ex: 123456abcdef.cloudfront.net) the entire site goes down.

My cloudfront address (ex: 123456abcdef.cloudfront.net) is resolving to the default Plesk domain. I just seem to have problems with proper Route 53 DNS configuration.

I have followed the instructions here with no success: https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/map-your-domain-at-route53-to-lightsail/4/

I have also looked at a similiar post on Stack Overflow here: [How to apply CDN with cloudfront - router 53 => lightsail instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58687789/how-to-apply-cdn-with-cloudfront-router-53-lightsail-instance) However, I have not configured my cloudfront distribution in cloudfront, but rather in Lightsail.

Here is an image of my apex DNS Record:
[Image of my A record entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDMJ8.jpg)

Do I need to create another record in my hosted zone? A record that continues to point the apex domain to the static IP?

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am responding to my own question with an answer I think addresses the problem in an alternate way.

I have been trying for a month to set up a CloudFront on my WordPress site running on a Lightsail Instance running Plesk using Route 53 as my DNS provider. I have finally been able to get it running. I installed the AWS for Wordpress Plugin. Follow this guide to set up a user.
[Plugin Setup AWS Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/WordPressPlugIn.html)

My preferred domain is [www.mydomain.ca](http://www.mydomain.ca). My WP site is setup to direct to [www.mydomain.ca](http://www.mydomain.ca) NOT mydomain.ca. In route 53 my apex domain (mydomain.ca) points to my static ip. The [www.mydomain.ca](http://www.mydomain.ca) record is set an ALIAS A record and points to the cloudfront domain name (123456abcdef.cloudfront.net). During set up the AWS WP pluging told me to set [www.mydomain.ca](http://www.mydomain.ca) to a CNAME ALIAS which will not work. I found some more useful documentation in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35208317/how-to-correctly-set-up-amazon-route-53-cloudfront-with-custom-origin) on SO.

It all seems to be working. However, you need to make sure you do not have any other cloudfront distributions connected to the origin (youdomain.ca), active or inactive, in the Cloudfront admin area OR the Lightsail admin area. This causes a conflict and the set up in the WP admin area will fail.

I hope this post helps someone and saves them a month &%$%ing around with Cloudfront Wordpress setup using Lightsail and Route 53.